# How to disable Request Method: OPTIONS with ember app kit

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

Since i'm using EAK, each time I save a model, I have an extra request method. It's more annoying then anything and I'd like to disable it. I haven't found anything in the documentation regarding this. Has anyone ever disabled it or am I stuck with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but this doesn't sound like a problem with Ember-App-Kit. Are you by any chance using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to send your requests? You say that it sends an `OPTIONS` request when you save a model, but you didn't mention that it sends one when it fetches a model. This makes me think that it's a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) that is unavoidable if you're using CORS. We had this same issue about a month ago and we decided to ditch CORS in favor of a proxy server.

I've never used Ember-App-Kit, but it's just a build tool, so I can't imagine how it would affect your Ember-Data adapter.

Comment: That was very enlightening. To anyone in the futur reading, EAK changes the way it communicate with the server using "Proxy" in the APIMethod config. The question now is, how do we set it back to standard. That is for another discussion. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, so it is EAK. Looks like they do a bit more config than I thought. It looks like you can change the settings for that in [this file](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/tasks/options/express-server.js).

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is that I can put either stub or proxy. By default, Ember-data simply sends a request to your own server. As you thought me, the Proxy method uses CORS to send request which can be useful some case, but not in mine. I wonder why there's no third option "Standard".

Comment: You can easily add a `standard` option [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/tasks/express-server.js#L25).

Comment: Great idea, I will definitely take a look at it. I'm sure it will be useful to other as well.